# Links in iframe application on Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, iframe, hyperlink

can anybody help me out, how to add a link to .. maybe a "headerimage",
inside a iframe application on facebook. So that the link will not open inside the iframe?

as an example, you click on a link directing to application2 .. it should open it in facebook,
but not inside your iframe.

thx sven

same problem on links to other user profiles..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="wherever.com" target="_top"><img.../></a>` should open a new page in the same window; which is essentially what happens when you are maneuvering through Facebook.

Unless you mean you want it to trigger an AJAX action...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to open some url in a new window, there are two ways to do it - by adding target="_blank" 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534659(VS.85).aspx

parameter to an A tag (your link),

or, by using open() method of JavaScript 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651.aspx.